# pdfSharp document orientation

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, orientation, pdfsharp

I want to change the orientation of a document created in c# wpf with pdfSharp, What should I do if I want to have a landscape document

here is my code

```
        private void savePDF()
    {

        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');

        MemoryStream lMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        Package package = Package.Open(lMemoryStream, FileMode.Create);
        XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(package);
        XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
        writer.Write(rapport);
        doc.Close();
        package.Close();
        var pdfXpsDoc = PdfSharp.Xps.XpsModel.XpsDocument.Open(lMemoryStream);
        PdfSharp.Xps.XpsConverter.Convert(pdfXpsDoc, "E:\\"+ date +".pdf", 0);



    }
```

Comment: Could you provide how do you create `rapport` document?

Comment: rapport is just the name of my grid so I have just add x:Name="rapport" in the xaml file

Comment: is your document only have one page?

Comment: yes it only has one page

Comment: here is what i get : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S5_owLqcO_RWt6MjdfX01WdHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: and here is what I want https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S5_owLqcO_WHUyRGE4V29oaE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: No specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first. that's mean the rapport grid is owned by an other element, you must create your grid in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Write your rapport to a `FixedDocument`:

```
FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
    PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
    FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();


      string savedrapport = XamlWriter.Save(rapport);

        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(savedrapport);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        Grid newrapportInstance = (Grid)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

        //Create first page of document
        fixedPage.Children.Add(newrapportInstance);
    ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
    // hard coded for A4
    fixedPage.Width = 11.69 * 96;
    fixedPage.Height = 8.27 * 96;
    fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);
    //Create any other required pages here

    MemoryStream lMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    Package package = Package.Open(lMemoryStream, FileMode.Create);
    XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(package);
    XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
    writer.Write(fixedDoc);
    doc.Close();
    package.Close();
    var pdfXpsDoc = PdfSharp.Xps.XpsModel.XpsDocument.Open(lMemoryStream);
    PdfSharp.Xps.XpsConverter.Convert(pdfXpsDoc, "E:\\"+ date +".pdf", 0);
```

Comment: switch between fixedPage.Width and fixedPage.Height Values if you want different orientation

Comment: I just tried but I have a 'System.InvalidOperationException' on the line fixedPage.Children.Add(rapport);

Comment: Yes but that's what I'have just seen is that the add need a IU Element in param and 'rapport' is a Visual

Comment: it's better but now I have a other problem here is what the grid looks like on my screen : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S5_owLqcO_WTRZaDAyX2NTeTg/view?usp=sharing and here is the pdf : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S5_owLqcO_dmc3WWtZT0I1cEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: that's mean your rapport is very large than A4; mark as answer and vote up the answer an we will fix this problem together

Comment: your page it must be A4? if yes Set the MaxWidth Property of the Grid in Xaml to MaxWidth ="1122.24"

Comment: no my page shouldn't be A4. I just want to save the grid to a PDF

Comment: Try switch fixed page height and width

Comment: I tried to increase fixedPage.Width and fixedPage.Height now I see all the grid but there is always text that overlaps and I just also tried to switch height and width but the grid is snipped

Comment: Set the fixedpage.height = rapport.actualheit and fixedpage.width = rapport.actualwidth

Comment: i tried but the result isn't good https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S5_owLqcO_Q21SRV9TUFphaFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: check your grid layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use printdialog，set the standard page size and orientation, the transform the width and height to fixeddocument page size. Don't set the actual number